# Ng-Repeat doesn't work properly on ng-included code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a Select class I have found on Internet, the problem is that if i create the option in the Select dinnamically, using angluar ng-repeat, the option will not be clickable, but if i create it manually, also using dynamic values, it can be clicked.

This is the code :

MainFile :

```
...
   <div id="SiteList" ng-controller="SiteController as siteCtrl" ng-if="masterCtrl.isUserLogged()" ng-include="'Select2/index.html'" ng-init="siteCtrl.getSites()"  >
...
```

This is Select2/index.html
...

```
<body>
  <div class="drop">
  <div class="option active placeholder" data-value="placeholder">
    Seleziona un sito
  </div>
  <div class="option" ng-repeat="sito in siteCtrl.siti"  data-value="{{sito.name}}">{{sito.name}}</div>

</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="Select2/js/index.js"></script>

</body>
```

...

Then the Select2/js/index.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop .option").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr("data-value"),
        $drop = $(".drop"),
        prevActive = $(".drop .option.active").attr("data-value"),
        options = $(".drop .option").length;
    $drop.find(".option.active").addClass("mini-hack");
    $drop.toggleClass("visible");
    $drop.removeClass("withBG");
    $(this).css("top");
    $drop.toggleClass("opacity");
    $(".mini-hack").removeClass("mini-hack");
    if ($drop.hasClass("visible")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $drop.addClass("withBG");
      }, 400 + options*100); 
    }
    triggerAnimation();
    if (val !== "placeholder" || prevActive === "placeholder") {
      $(".drop .option").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    };
  });

  function triggerAnimation() {
    var finalWidth = $(".drop").hasClass("visible") ? 22 : 20;
    $(".drop").css("width", "24em");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".drop").css("width", finalWidth + "em");
    }, 400);
  }
});
```

Anyone has any idea about how to resolve this?

Comment: ng-include is not an iframe, script won't loads and the body element is redonant with the one from the top level. If you want to make reusable components from jQuery/Vanilla/whatever, check the `directives` documentation of angularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid mixing Angular.js and jQuery.

Instead you can use Angular version of Select2:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select